# Getting exception "orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 0"

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data

I created stored procedure in my DB, below is the procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`administrator`@`%` PROCEDURE 
`express_delivery_order`(IN in_appname  varbinary(20), IN in_refid varbinary(20), IN in_shiptoparty varbinary(20), IN in_speed int)
BEGIN
    IF in_shiptoparty IS NULL THEN 
        select sd.dealerId dealer_id,sd.subdealerId subdealer_Id, sd.deliveryPoint,
        'AS01JC8716' truck_no,'4248303570' stonumber, 'BGM1300-OB-CLK-210707-00446' yardid, 
        'RGP CEMENT FACTORY_FPD' distance, '2.5 hrs' calculated_eta, 
        'ABC' from_source, 'XYZ' to_source 
        from schema1.subdealer sd, 
        schema1.address_new an,
        schema1.st_pf_mapping pfm 
        WHERE sd.dealerid = an.addressid 
        and pfm.Territory = an.salesterritory 
        and pfm.Partnr_Func ='Z1'
        and vendor = in_refid;
        ELSE      
           
        SELECT sd.dealerId dealer_id,sd.subdealerId subdealer_Id, sd.deliveryPoint,
            'AS01JC8716' truck_no,'4248303570' stonumber, 'BGM1300-OB-CLK-210707-00446' yardid, 
            'RGP CEMENT FACTORY_FPD' distance, '2.5 hrs' calculated_eta, 
            'ABC' from_source, 'XYZ' to_source 
            FROM schema1.subdealer sd, 
            schema1.address_new an
            WHERE sd.subdealerid = an.addressid 
            and sd.subdealerid = in_shiptoparty;
                 
        END IF ;    
    END
```

I have Spring boot application. In my Repository class I invoked below procedure as below:

```
List<ExpressDeliveryOrderDTO> fetchExpressDeliveryOrderDetails(@Param("appName") String appName, @Param("refId")  String refId,
    @Param("shipToParty") String shipToParty,  @Param("speed")  String speed);
```

Also, I created DTO for same to get Result

```
import com.demo1.smartd.dto.CompanyWiseAgingSuvidhaDto;
import com.demo1.smartd.responseDTO.expressDeliveryDTO.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import lombok.*;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;
import javax.persistence.ColumnResult;
import javax.persistence.ConstructorResult;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import javax.persistence.SqlResultSetMapping;
import java.util.Random;

    
@MappedSuperclass
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "ExpressDeliveryOrderDTO",
    classes = @ConstructorResult(targetClass = ExpressDeliveryOrderDTO.class, columns = {
    @ColumnResult(name = "dealer_id", type = String.class), @ColumnResult(name = "subdealer_Id", type = String.class),
    @ColumnResult(name = "deliveryPoint", type = String.class), @ColumnResult(name = "truck_no", type = String.class),
    @ColumnResult(name = "stonumber", type = String.class), @ColumnResult(name = "yardid", type = String.class),
    @ColumnResult(name = "distance", type = String.class), @ColumnResult(name = "calculated_eta", type = String.class),
    @ColumnResult(name = "from_source", type = String.class), @ColumnResult(name = "to_source", type = String.class)
}))
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@SuperBuilder
public class ExpressDeliveryOrderDTO {
    private String dealer_id;
    
    private String subdealer_Id;
            
    private String deliveryPoint;
            
    private String truck_no;
            
    private String stonumber;
            
    private String yardid;
            
    private String distance;
            
    private String calculated_eta;
            
    private String from_source;
            
    private String to_source;
            
    public ExpressDeliveryOrderDTO(String dealer_id,
        String subdealer_Id,
        String deliveryPoint,
        String truck_no,
        String stonumber,
        String yardid,
        String distance,
        String calculated_eta,
        String from_source,
        String to_source) {
        super();
        this.dealer_id = dealer_id;
        this.subdealer_Id = subdealer_Id;
        this.deliveryPoint = deliveryPoint;
        this.truck_no = truck_no;
        this.stonumber = stonumber;
        this.yardid = yardid;
        this.distance = distance;
        this.calculated_eta = calculated_eta;
        this.from_source = from_source;
        this.to_source = to_source;
    }
            
    public DealerDetailsDTO convertToDealerDetailDTO() {
        DealerDetailsDTO dealerDetailsDTO = new DealerDetailsDTO();
        dealerDetailsDTO.setDealerId(this.getDealer_id());
        dealerDetailsDTO.setDealerName(this.getDealer_id() + "_dealerName");
        dealerDetailsDTO.setPlant(this.getFrom_source());
        dealerDetailsDTO.setE2e(this.getDeliveryPoint());
        return dealerDetailsDTO;
    }
            
    public SubDealerDetailsDTO convertToSubDealerDetailsDTO() {
        SubDealerDetailsDTO subDealerDetailsDTO = new SubDealerDetailsDTO();
        subDealerDetailsDTO.setDealerId(this.getDealer_id());
        subDealerDetailsDTO.setDealerName(this.getDealer_id() + "_dealerName");
        subDealerDetailsDTO.setPlant(this.getFrom_source());
        subDealerDetailsDTO.setE2e(this.getTo_source());
            
        return subDealerDetailsDTO;
    }
            
    public DealerSubDealerDeliveryPointsDTO convertToDealerSubDealerDeliveryPointsDTO() {
        DealerSubDealerDeliveryPointsDTO dealerSubDealerDeliveryPointsDTO = new DealerSubDealerDeliveryPointsDTO();
            
        dealerSubDealerDeliveryPointsDTO.setDealerId(this.getDealer_id());
        dealerSubDealerDeliveryPointsDTO.setDealerName(this.getDealer_id() + "_dealerName");
        dealerSubDealerDeliveryPointsDTO.setPlant(this.getFrom_source());
        dealerSubDealerDeliveryPointsDTO.setE2e(this.getTo_source());
            
        return dealerSubDealerDeliveryPointsDTO;
    }
            
    public E2EDepotDTO convertToE2EDepotDTO() {
        E2EDepotDTO e2EDepotDTO = new E2EDepotDTO();
        e2EDepotDTO.setEta(this.getCalculated_eta());
        e2EDepotDTO.setProductCode(String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt(1000) + 1));
        e2EDepotDTO.setNumberOfVehicles(new Random().nextInt(100) + 1);
        e2EDepotDTO.setVehicleNumber(this.getTruck_no());
        e2EDepotDTO.setVehicleQuantity(new Random().nextInt(1000) + 1);
            
            
        return e2EDepotDTO;
    }
            
    public PlantsDTO convertToPlantDTO() {
        PlantsDTO plantsDTO = new PlantsDTO();
        plantsDTO.setEta(this.getCalculated_eta());
        plantsDTO.setProductName("product-" + String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt(100) + 1));
        plantsDTO.setNosOfVehicles(new Random().nextInt(100 ) + 1);
        plantsDTO.setVehicleMinQuantity(0);
        plantsDTO.setVehicleMaxQuantity(new Random().nextInt(10000) + 1);
        plantsDTO.setProductQuantity(new Random().nextInt(5000 ) + 1);
            
        return plantsDTO;
    }
}
```

While making relevant API call, I am getting below exception:

```
ERROR:requestId=226910b2-5bf7-472e-9b6d-bdb32bb88005  com.test.smartd.serviceimpl.ExpressDeliveryServiceImpl - Error occured in getDeliveryPointList org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No Dialect mapping for
JDBC type: 0; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 0
```

I referred many links , but not getting where I am missing. I am using MySQL DB

Below is my application.properties file:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate: ERROR

server.servlet.context-path=/demo1

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout = 20000 
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle= 10
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size= 100
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=10000
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime= 300000
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit =true

spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings= true

#spring.jpa.show-sql = false

# ==============================================================
# = Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
# ==============================================================

#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
#spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

# ==============================================================
# = The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
# ==============================================================
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false

server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
```

Comment: Can you show your application.properties ?

Comment: @BigZed added application.properties file above

Comment: Please check this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-stored-procedures)

Comment: @MohammadJavad I already referred this link. I think , I am not missing anything

Comment: Hi ! @user3265739, i am not very familiar with calling stored procedures using JPA but I got a great article explaining how here : https://thorben-janssen.com/call-stored-procedures-jpa/. Hope it will help.

Comment: Hi @BigZed, i already refered this link